# Extract First and Last word from a string and remove them if matches the third one using C#

Tags: c#, .net, string

My string is like this:

```
string str = "Psppsp palm springs airport, 3400 e tahquitz canyon way, Palm springs, CA, US, 92262-6966 psppsp";
```

I get the string "psppsp" separately and need to compare it with the first and last word in str and if found (at first or last word), need to remove it from str.

I need to know the best and fastest way for the same.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve], with at least 6 inputs specified and for each of them a documented expected output.

Comment: We're not going to help you unless you show us what you've tried and/or what research you have done before posting here.

Comment: first of all split string at space delimeter then verify if first and last member of string array are equal and then remove them, after that use string.join to convert it back to original. ***Thats A Hint For WHat You Need To Do But We Are Not Code Writing Service So We Cant Write Whole Code For your problem, or show the code you tried***

Comment: Looks like homework to me...

Comment: Because changing the string means allocating a new one, the "best and fastest" way depends a lot on the broader context of your code. Simply optimizing this particular operation on its own is not likely to be your best bet.

Comment: @Nyerguds -- so what?

Comment: @OP, see [this](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Your requirement in the title is different to the one in the question body. What's with this third word, is it relevant? What's the desired result at all?

Comment: i wont answer this question since it looks like a homework for me :v

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think with "third word" he means the provided string that needs to be matched.

Comment: @rory.ap see [this](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems). SO is not a code writing service, and students need to get the experience of doing research so they can solve trivial problems like this on their own. Also, [from the "off topic" help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): _Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._

Comment: Does not look like homework to me. Maybe OP is cleansing a database. Maybe there are thousands of entries and that's why they want _best and fastest way_....

Comment: "Psppsp" is code of a particular location(one such code, there are lakhs of them). Till now our code was working fine where we got a perfect address from the suppliers web service, but somehow they are now putting in the location codes (sometimes at the start, sometimes at the end and sometime at both locations). Now we need to handle this case.

Comment: @Nyerguds -- You basically just elaborated on my statement.  Homework is not out of bounds, as long as you show effort.

Comment: @AmitVerma "Fastest" isn't going to be hindered by the extremely basic string manipulation required to solve your problem, virtually all of your speed constraints will be in the read/write operations from wherever those strings are stored. (Assuming that this isn't a homework question, not that I care either way.) Look up `string.IndexOf` and `string.Substring`, that's all you need.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this. Here's one way using Regex. You can pre-compile the regex which will speed things up if you are doing this on many strings:

```
string str = "Psppsp palm springs airport, 3400 e tahquitz canyon way, Palm springs, CA, US, 92262-6966 psppsp";

string match = "psppsp";

// Build 2 re-usable regexes
string pattern1 = "^" + match + "\\s*";
string pattern2 = "\\s*" + match + "$";
Regex rgx1 = new Regex(pattern1, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Regex rgx2 = new Regex(pattern2, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// Apply the 2 regexes
str = rgx1.Replace(rgx2.Replace(str, ""), "");
```

If there's no chance the match will be elsewhere on the string, you can use linq. This involves converting the array returned by split to a list:

```
// Convert to list
var tempList = new List<string>(str.Split());
// Remove all occurences of match
tempList.RemoveAll(x => String.Compare(x, match, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0);
// Convert list back to string
str = String.Join(" ", tempList.ToArray());
```

Or, a more simple method

```
if (str.StartsWith(match, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) {
    str = str.Substring(match.Length);
}
if (str.EndsWith(match, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) {
    str = str.Substring(0, str.Length - match.Length);
}
str = str.Trim();
```

Not sure which (if any) of these is "best". I like the last one.

Comment: Regexes are both overkill and not likely to be very efficient compared to alternatives, even if compiled (due to the simple nature of the operation), but if you are going to use them, don't forget `Regex.Escape` when cobbling them together dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

The fasted way is O(n). Below is an example of the code, it can be improved.

```
        string str = "Psppsp palm springs airport, 3400 e tahquitz canyon way, Palm springs, CA, US, 92262-6966 psppsp";
        string word = "psppsp";

        // Check if str and word are equals
        if (str == word)
        {
            str = "";
        }

        // Check Firt word in str
        if (str.Length > word.Length)
        {
            bool equal = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
            {
                if (str[i] != word[i])
                {
                    equal = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (equal && str[word.Length] == ' ')
            {
                str = str.Substring(word.Length);
            }
        }

        // Check Last word in str
        if (str.Length > word.Length)
        {
            bool equal = true;
            for (int i = word.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (str[str.Length - word.Length + i] != word[i])
                {
                    equal = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (equal)
            {
                str = str.Substring(0, str.Length - word.Length);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use str.StartsWith(x), str.EndsWith(x), str.Contains(x), str.IndexOf(x) to find and locate your search string and str.Substring(start, len) to change the string. There are many many ways you can achieve this string manipulation, but you asked for...

Best and fastest: Let's use some completely safe 'unsafe' code so we can work with pointers.

```
    // note this is an extension method so you need to include it in a static class
    public unsafe static string RemoveCaseInsensitive(this string source, string remove)
    {
        // convert to lower to enable case insensitive comparison
        string sourceLower = source.ToLower();

        // define working pointers
        int srcPos = 0;
        int srcLen = source.Length;
        int dstPos = 0;
        int rmvPos = 0;
        int rmvLen = remove.Length;

        // create char arrays to work with in the 'unsafe' code
        char[] destChar = new char[srcLen];

        fixed (char* srcPtr = source, srcLwrPtr = sourceLower, rmvPtr = remove, dstPtr = destChar)
        {
            // loop through each char in the source array
            while (srcPos < srcLen)
            {
                // copy the char and move dest position on
                *(dstPtr + dstPos) = *(srcPtr + srcPos);
                dstPos++;

                // compare source char to remove char
                // note we're comparing against the sourceLower but copying from source so that
                // a case insensitive remove preserves the rest of the string's original case
                if (*(srcLwrPtr + srcPos) == *(rmvPtr + rmvPos))
                {
                    rmvPos++;
                    if (rmvPos == rmvLen)
                    {
                        // if the whole string has been matched
                        // reverse dest position back by length of remove string
                        dstPos -= rmvPos;
                        rmvPos = 0;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    rmvPos = 0;
                }

                // move to next char in source
                srcPos++;
            }
        }

        // return the string
        return new string(destChar, 0, dstPos);
    }
```

Usage:

```
str.RemoveCaseInsensitive("Psppsp"); // this will remove all instances throughout the string
str.RemoveCaseInsensitive("Psppsp "); // space included at the end so in your example will remove the first instance and trailing space.
str.RemoveCaseInsensitive(" psppsp"); // space included at the start so in your example will remove the final instance and leading space.
```

Why use unsafe code you may ask? When dealing with arrays, every time you point to an element in that array, a bounds check is done. So str[1], str[2], str[3], etc each has overhead. So when you're dealing with this sort of check on thousands of characters, it adds up. Using unsafe code enables accessing memory directly using pointers. There is no bounds check, or anything else slowing the operation down. The difference in performance can be massive.

As an example of the performance difference, I have created two versions of this. One safe using standard string pointers and the unsafe one. I have created a string by recursively adding thousands of copies of strings to keep and to remove. The results are clear, the unsafe version completes in half the time of the safe version. These methods are identical apart from being safe vs unsafe.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public unsafe static string RemoveUnsafe(this string source, string remove)
    {
        // convert to lower to enable case insensitive comparison
        string sourceLower = source.ToLower();

        // define working pointers
        int srcPos = 0;
        int srcLen = source.Length;
        int dstPos = 0;
        int rmvPos = 0;
        int rmvLen = remove.Length;

        // create char arrays to work with in the 'unsafe' code
        char[] destChar = new char[srcLen];

        fixed (char* srcPtr = source, srcLwrPtr = sourceLower, rmvPtr = remove, dstPtr = destChar)
        {
            // loop through each char in the source array
            while (srcPos < srcLen)
            {
                // copy the char and move dest position on
                *(dstPtr + dstPos) = *(srcPtr + srcPos);
                dstPos++;

                // compare source char to remove char
                // note we're comparing against the sourceLower but copying from source so that
                // a case insensitive remove preserves the rest of the string's original case
                if (*(srcLwrPtr + srcPos) == *(rmvPtr + rmvPos))
                {
                    rmvPos++;
                    if (rmvPos == rmvLen)
                    {
                        // if the whole string has been matched
                        // reverse dest position back by length of remove string
                        dstPos -= rmvPos;
                        rmvPos = 0;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    rmvPos = 0;
                }

                // move to next char in source
                srcPos++;
            }
        }

        // return the string
        return new string(destChar, 0, dstPos);
    }

    public static string RemoveSafe(this string source, string remove)
    {
        // convert to lower to enable case insensitive comparison
        string sourceLower = source.ToLower();
        string removeLower = remove.ToLower();

        // define working pointers
        int srcPos = 0;
        int srcLen = source.Length;
        int dstPos = 0;
        int rmvPos = 0;
        int rmvLen = remove.Length;

        // create char arrays to work with in the 'unsafe' code
        char[] destChar = new char[srcLen];

        // loop through each char in the source array
        while (srcPos < srcLen)
        {
            // copy the char and move dest position on
            destChar[dstPos] = source[srcPos];
            dstPos++;

            // compare source char to remove char
            // note we're comparing against the sourceLower but copying from source so that
            // a case insensitive remove preserves the rest of the string's original case
            if (sourceLower[srcPos] == removeLower[rmvPos])
            {
                rmvPos++;
                if (rmvPos == rmvLen)
                {
                    // if the whole string has been matched
                    // reverse dest position back by length of remove string
                    dstPos -= rmvPos;
                    rmvPos = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                rmvPos = 0;
            }

            // move to next char in source
            srcPos++;
        }

        // return the string
        return new string(destChar, 0, dstPos);
    }
}
```

This is the benchmarking:

```
internal static class StringRemoveTests
{
    private static string CreateString()
    {
        string x = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        string y = "GoodBye";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            sb.Append(i % 3 == 0 ? y : x);

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private static int RunBenchMarkUnsafe()
    {
        string str = CreateString();
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        string str2 = str.RemoveUnsafe("goodBYE");
        DateTime end = DateTime.Now;

        return (int)(end - start).TotalMilliseconds;
    }
    private static int RunBenchMarkSafe()
    {
        string str = CreateString();
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        string str2 = str.RemoveSafe("goodBYE");
        DateTime end = DateTime.Now;

        return (int)(end - start).TotalMilliseconds;
    }

    public static void RunBenchmarks()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Safe version: " + RunBenchMarkSafe());
        Console.WriteLine("Unsafe version: " + RunBenchMarkUnsafe());
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringRemoveTests.RunBenchmarks();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The output: (results are milliseconds)

```
// 1st run
Safe version: 569
Unsafe version: 260

// 2nd run
Safe version: 709
Unsafe version: 329

// 3rd run
Safe version: 486
Unsafe version: 279
```

Comment: You can simply do `fixed char* pSource = source` without any need for going through character array allocations first. Nor is `Buffer.BlockCopy` necessary, as `String` has a constructor that operates directly on pointers and ranges. I don't fancy a micro-optimization competition here (certainly not without benchmarks), but this has a lot of obvious chaff that likely negates any purported benefit of skipping bounds checks.

Comment: I see you can point to a string. Don't know why I thought you couldn't Updated.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I have added some benchmarks as you made me want to know how much faster it is. So, the answer is that it is twice as fast to use unsafe code, but it was already fast to begin with.

Comment: If you're serious about benchmarking, do yourself a favor and use [benchmark.net](http://benchmarkdotnet.org/). There are many pitfalls with correct micro-benchmarking in .NET (JIT warmup, initial allocation overhead, etc.) and it takes care of all of that for you, with a delightfully simple API. (Disclaimer: no, I'm not paid to shill it. :-))